# I'm finding WPF's Canvas drawing to be weirdly designed. Why does it prefer argument-less constructors?

Tags: c#, wpf

First off, I'm sorry for the wording of the title; I'm not really sure how to concisely state my confusion without it sounding inflammatory.

I'm very new (two days) to making UIs with WPF.  So far, I'm absolutely loving most things about it.  However, drawing to the canvas seems very unintuitive to me.  I was hoping that someone here could explain either a) why it's better this way, or b) that I'm just using it wrong.

I learned computer drawing on Java's Graphics2D canvas, which is similar to GDI+.  To draw a rectangle at specific coordinates in a space, I call something like `canvas.drawRectangle(x, y, w, h, color)`.  With WPF, however, I've noticed that Rectangle objects have no arguments in their constructors, which means it requires significantly more lines to draw one:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
rect.Width = w;
rect.Height = h;
rect.Color = Colors.Black;
... // a whole line for each parameter
Canvas.SetLeft(rect, x);
Canvas.Setleft(rect, y);
c.Children.Add(rect);
```

It seems unnecessarily verbose, which makes me think that I'm missing something (either a benefit or a shortcut).  I understand the benefits of WPF over GDI+ and why some things need to be structured in a certain way, but I was expecting to be able to do something like this:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(w, h, Colors.Black);
c.AddChild(rect, x, y);
```

Sorry for the lengthy post, and that it's not a standard "How do I do *_*?" SO question.  I really hope this didn't come across as whiny; I'm just trying to learn a new technology and didn't expect something so different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additionally to Tim's answer, i want to mention that you can write the Rectangle instantiation together with its initialization in one line:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle { Width = w, Height = h, Fill = Brushes.Black };
```

When using this object initializer syntax with the default constructor of a type, it is allowed to omit the parentheses.

If the method call sequence

```
Canvas.SetLeft(rect, x);
Canvas.SetTop(rect, y);
c.Children.Add(rect);
```

should be refactored into a dedicated method, an extension method can be used:

```
namespace MyExtensionMethods
{
    public static class CanvasExtensions
    {
        public static int AddChild(this Canvas canvas, UIElement element, int x, int y)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(element, x);
            Canvas.SetTop(element, y);
            return canvas.Children.Add(element);
        }
    }
}
```

In your source code file where you create and place the rectangle on the canvas, you first need to import the namespace of the extension method(s):

```
using MyExtensionMethods;
```

Then, we just use the object initializer syntax and the extension method we just implemented:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle { Width = w, Height = h, Fill = Brushes.Black };
c.AddChild(rect, x, y);
```

That's pretty compact, isn't it?

Comment: Cool, thanks.  Is there any way to do the positioning/adding of the rectangle to the canvas in a similarly in-line way?

Comment: @Benjin, no because SetLeft,SetTop,etc. are not properties of Rectangle which can be initialized during instantiation (in WPF-speak they are so-called "attached properties" Canvas.Left,Canvas.Top etc., but they are not real .NET type properties). If you have many of such almost identical code sequences with many lines in your code, then you might want refactor them into a dedicated method.

Comment: Sorry, I meant in-line for when I add it to the canvas' children.  I know the shape itself has no knowledge of its position.

Comment: @Benjin, no you cannot use object initializer syntax for "beautifying" of method calls, because (as the name implies) this syntax is only for object initialization. (Note that both Canvas.SetLeft() and c.Children.Add() are method calls)

Comment: I was more looking for an overload (or something) that would effectively be `canvas.Children.Add(rect, x, y)`, but it seems one doesn't exist.  Looks like helper methods are the way to go for me.

Comment: @Benjin, yupp, i agree, putting the code sequence in your own method is the best approach. If you want to make it fancy, you could implement it as an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx) for the Canvas type, so the call of your method could then look like: `c.AddChild(rect, x, y)` ;)

Comment: Extension methods look perfect for me.  Thanks!

Comment: Okay, i have just provided an example for the extension method.

Comment: Can I also use extension methods to create new constructors (say, for Rectangle)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45239/discussion-between-elgonzo-and-benjin)

Answer (score 3):

Without making judgments on whether data binding is appropriate in your situation, it is certainly possible:

```
// Shapes.cs
public class Shape
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double W { get; set; }
    public double H { get; set; }
}

public class Rectangle : Shape { }

public class Circle : Shape { }

public class Triangle : Shape
{
    public double Angle { get; set; }
}
```

```
<!-- Window.xaml -->
<!-- Itemscontrol will take each item in a bound collection (in this case, shapes) and create a visual based off of data templates -->
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding shapes}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <!-- data templates let us control the visual representation of a given class -->
        <!-- DataType=Rectangle causes the contents of this datatemplate to be shown for -->
        <!-- each instance of a rectangle found in the shapes collection. -->
        <!-- Since we do not specify a size, the contents will fill to their parent, which -->
        <!-- we are constraining in the ItemsContainerStyle -->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Rectangle}">
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Circle}">
            <Ellipse Fill="Blue" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Triangle}">
            <!-- Since we are specifying a specific geometry for the triangle, we want it -->
            <!-- to scale to the dimensions supplied.  Viewbox does that for us. -->
            <Viewbox>
                <Polygon Points="0,0 80,50, 0,100" Stroke="Black" Fill="Black">
                    <Polygon.LayoutTransform>
                        <!-- We also transform the coordinate space by rotating it by the -->
                        <!-- angle specified in the Triangle instance -->
                        <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Angle}" />
                    </Polygon.LayoutTransform>
                </Polygon>
            </Viewbox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <!-- Here we are swapping out the standard stack-panel for a canvas -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <!-- And we set the positioning of the items within the itemscontrol. -->
    <!-- These must be set via style, rather than directly, since the items control -->
    <!-- wraps each item in a ContentPresenter (ItemsContainerStyle.Template) -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding W}" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding H}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

```
// Window.xaml.cs
    public MainWindow()
    {
        shapes = new ObservableCollection<Shape>();
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = this;

        shapes.Add(new Rectangle() { X = 50, Y = 43, H = 15, W = 59 });
        shapes.Add(new Rectangle() { X = 67, Y = 43, H = 20, W = 30 });
        shapes.Add(new Circle() { X = 50, Y = 43, H = 15, W = 59 });
        shapes.Add(new Triangle() { X = 100, Y = 100, H = 40, W = 40, Angle = 20 });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Shape> shapes { get; set; }
```

Produces:
[image: Shapes on a window]

The benefit is the vector based, databindable, stylable template goodness.  For more on databinding, [see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480224.aspx).  DataTemplates are [explained here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If you just want to draw to a bitmap surface á la GDI, directly use a [`RenderContext` (the analog to `Graphics`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can [implement your own FrameworkElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingvisual%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in much the same way you would override the `OnPaint` method of yore:

```
    class DrawingElement : FrameworkElement
{
    private List<Shape> shapes;
    private DrawingVisual visual;

    public DrawingElement(IEnumerable<Shape> shapesToDraw)
        : base()
    {
        this.shapes = new List<Shape>(shapesToDraw);
        this.visual = new DrawingVisual();

        this.AddVisualChild(visual);

        render();
    }

    private void render()
    {
        var dc = this.visual.RenderOpen();
        foreach (var shape in shapes)
        {
            if (shape is Rectangle)
            {
                var rect = (Rectangle)shape;
                dc.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Red, new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1), new Rect(rect.X, rect.Y, rect.W, rect.H));
            }
            else if (shape is Circle)
            {
                var rect = (Circle)shape;
                dc.DrawEllipse(Brushes.Blue, new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1),
                    new Point(rect.X + rect.W / 2, rect.Y + rect.H / 2),
                    rect.W / 2, rect.H / 2);
            }
            else if (shape is Triangle)
            {
                // trig goes here
            }
        }
        dc.Close();
    }

    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    {
        if (index != 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

        return visual;
    }

    protected override int VisualChildrenCount { get { return 1; } }
}
```

Comment: That looks rather impressive, and the end result (of simplicity) in the .cs file is enticing.  However, I have almost no familiarity with XAML constructs; could I bother you to comment what's happening in the XAML bit so I can understand it better?  (specifically the data template bits) Thanks!

Comment: I added a brief explanation, but databinding, templates and styles are all very core to WPF, and a larger topic than I can adequately address.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be used in XAML, a class needs to be public and have a parameterless constructor. When working with WPF, you should almost never be constructing your UI using C# code, so I imagine most of the classes were designed with XAML instantiation in mind, with C# instantiation a distant afterthought.

Here's an example of creating a rectangle inside a canvas using XAML:

```
<Canvas>
    <Rectangle Canvas.Left="20" Fill="Black" Width="30" Height="40" />
</Canvas>
```

Comment: The program I'm trying to make involves reading in a "map" file then drawing it on a canvas in the XAML, so the number, position, types, colors, etc of the shapes are completely dynamic and can only created during runtime.  Is there a better way to do what I'm attempting with WPF?

Comment: Typically you would use data binding to handle dynamic data in WPF. Every `FrameworkElement` has a `DataContext` property and you can bind to properties on said data context from the XAML. It's a little much for me to try to explain in one comment, but here is a link to Microsoft's overview if you want some place to get started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I think I understand data binding pretty well, but I don't think (obviously, correct me if I'm wrong) it's applicable to this.  I'm reading in shape/object metadata from a config file, and drawing the corresponding shapes on the screen.  Data binding is used when you _know_ there's a one-to-one relationship between the dynamic elements on-screen and their logical counterparts (string to string, number to number, list to list).

Comment: You're right that you can't bind the children of a `Canvas` to a collection. You need a more advanced control like an `ItemsControl` for that. Unfortunately, none of the default panels (to my knowledge) are a very good fit for plotting geometric data. You can write your own panel, but honestly, this can be a daunting task. The way you were going originally may be the most expedient, even if the code can be a bit tedious. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.